# Polymer 1.0 paper-input text highlighting

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have just been testing some polymer 1.0 elements. I noticed that using the paper-input element it is not possible to drag highlight text entered into it.

It is possible to use keyboard shortcuts to highlight text and it is also possible to double click.

I have checked the documentation and i cannot see if this is intended functionality, can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Could you give an example of your code? I have played with the [paper-input demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?view=demo:demo/index.html) and I can highlight text inside it using the mouse.

Comment: i would love to but have been unsuccessful in importing the elements into plnkr or similar, it seems to be that there is an issue only when the input is nested in other elements

Comment: [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XZRniOOU1bWYkEDrVIdZ) is a plunker set up you can use. Alternatively, just edit your question and paste some snippets in there.

Comment: Thanks for that, here is the plnkr demonstrating the issue http://plnkr.co/edit/0fwg9VSbtYpF1sXi4ura?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in the recent update to iron-input or paper-input.
It works fine in the demo now.
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?view=demo:demo/index.html

Comment: As far as i was aware it has always worked fine in their demo, have you tried the plnkr in the above comment?

Comment: Did you try updating to the new paper elements? It fixed this problem for me in my code.

Comment: Yes, this is using the latest Polymer 1.0 elements

Comment: Polymer 1.0 elements is not new enough. Some elements have 1.0.3/1.0.4 which contain a fix for highlighting code. Running "bower update" pulls the newest elements that contain bug fixes.  That plnkr code does work if you update to the newest polymer elements. I just tried it on my PC with the newest Chrome. Also the plnkr code is missing the closing </paper-material>.

Comment: I applied the update to my components and it seems to have solved the issue. I guess they have applied the fixes in the time between question and answer, which is good enough for me.

Comment: Feel free to give me credit by clicking accepted answer.