# Highlight Text Programmatically in Polymer Paper Input

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, html-input

I have several polymer [paper-input](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input) elements on a polymer app. When one of these elements is focused, I'd like the text input of the input be highlighted ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936418/polymer-1-0-paper-input-text-highlighting)) so that if a user just starts typing, the existing value of the input is overwritten.

Is there a way to highlight the text programmatically on focus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
inputElement.$.input.select()
```

Would be nice if this were documented somewhere.

Comment: inputElement has a property `inputElement`, which is a html input and has a `select` method

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/Polymer.PaperInputBehavior), `inputElement` will return a reference to the actual HTML input element implemented in `<paper-input>`.  You need to access the native element as `select()` is not implemented directly in `<paper-input>`.

HTML:

```
<paper-input id="my-input" value="[[myInputText]]></paper-input>
```

JavaScript:

```
querySelector('#my-input').inputElement.select();
```

Comment: I don't know why, but `querySelector('#my-input').inputElement.inputElement.select()` did the trick for me